Understand the first unit group $U^{(1)}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module
Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q_p}$. It is well-known that $K^\times$ is isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/(q-1)\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p^\alpha\times\mathbb{Z}_p^d$, where $q$ is the order of the residue field, $p^\alpha$ is the number of root of unity of $p$-power in $K$, and $d=[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]$. In the proof, we firstly get $K^\times\cong p^\mathbb{Z}\times\mathcal{O}_{K}^\times$ by the valuation map and $\mathcal{O}_K^\times\cong k^\times\times U^{(1)}$ through the Teichmüller uniformizer, where $k^\times$ is the residue field. Then we have to use the structure theorem of modules over PID, where we view $U^{(1)}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module either through the profinite completion of $U^{(1)}$: $U^{(1)}\cong\varprojlim_n U^{(1)}/U^{(n)}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p\cong\varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$, or directly define $x^a$ for $x\in U^{(1)}$ and $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$.
What is the motivation to consider $U^{(1)}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module? When $1>\frac{e}{p-1}$, where $e$ is the ramification degree, I can see this through log and exp between $U^{(1)}$ and $\mathfrak{m}$, but I'm not sure about other cases.

I think the motivation is "because one can" and "because modules over an extraordinarily nice ring like $\mathbb Z_p$ are easily classified". What more (or what other kind of) "motivation" are you looking for?

Making $U^{(1)}$ into a $\mathbf Z_p$-module is the simplest example of $p$-adic interpolation, namely interpolation of $\mathbf Z$-exponents to $\mathbf Z_p$-exponents.
The Lubin-Tate approach to local class field theory shows the usefulness of this in much greater generality.  When $L/K$ is a finite extension of local fields, $A = \mathcal O_K$, and $\pi$ is a uniformizer of $A$, the formal group law built from a Lubin-Tate series in $A[[T]]$ associated to $\pi$ gives the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_L$ of $\mathcal O_L$ a nonobvious $A$-module structure. (Lubin has said he prefers the term "formal $A$-module" to "formal group".) The $\pi^n$-torsion points in $L$ of this $A$-module structure give you interesting totally ramified abelian extensions of $K$, and you need to make $L$ large enough to pick up all the $\pi^n$-torsion. Maybe you'll think you don't "need" the $A$-module structure on all of $\mathfrak m_L$ since we just use the $\pi$-power torsion, but it's simpler to think about $\mathfrak m_L$ as an $A$-module and then a (finite) submodule of it, which automatically inherits the $A$-module structure, rather than trying to make the $\pi^n$-torsion points into an $A$-module without already having them live in a larger set that is already an $A$-module.
In particular, if $K = \mathbf Q_p$, then Lubin-Tate formal groups over $\mathbf Z_p$ make $\mathfrak m_L$ into a $\mathbf Z_p$-module in a nonobvious way. When the formal group law on $\mathfrak m_L$ is the formal multiplicative group (this is associated to the Lubin-Tate series $(1+T)^p - 1$ that is just a polynomial), this formal group law on $\mathfrak m_L$ is just a shifted version of ordinary multiplication on $1+\mathfrak m_L$ by $t \mapsto t-1$. Thus the $\mathbf Z_p$-module structure on $1 + \mathfrak m_L$ is the simplest example of an aspect of how local class field theory is usually developed.
